react-hook-form with nextjs server actions
I have a client component in nextjs that uses shadcn-ui,react-hook-form and zod. The client component is as follows:
'use client';

import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';
import { CaretSortIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { useRef } from 'react';

import { cn } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from '@/components/ui/form';
import { Calendar } from '@/components/ui/calendar';
import { CalendarIcon, CheckIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import {
  Popover,
  PopoverContent,
  PopoverTrigger,
} from '@/components/ui/popover';
import { toast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast';
import * as React from 'react';
import { VirtualizedCommand } from '@/components/ui/virtualized-combobox';
import {
  RemDbStatus,
  TFormUpdateSchema,
  UpdateRemediation,
  Option,
  State,
} from '@/app/lib/definitions';
import {
  fetchTechVersion,
  fetchCurrentRemediationData,
  UpdateRemediationAction,
} from '@/app/lib/actions';
import {
  Command,
  CommandInput,
  CommandList,
  CommandEmpty,
  CommandGroup,
  CommandItem,
} from '@/components/ui/command';
import { Textarea } from '@/components/ui/textarea';
// @ts-ignore
import { useActionState } from 'react';

export function ComboboxForm({
  it_services,
  remediation_types,
}: {
  it_services: { it_service: string }[];
  remediation_types: { remediation_type: string | null }[];
}) {
  const form = useForm<TFormUpdateSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(UpdateRemediation),
  });
  const formRef = useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);
  const { watch } = form;

  console.log(`these are the form values`, form.getValues());
  const options_service = it_services.map((item) => ({
    value: item.it_service,
    label: item.it_service,
  }));

  const [serviceopen, setServiceOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [techopen, setTechOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [remediate, setRemedDateOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [remedtype, setRemedTypeOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [techoptions, setTechOptions] = React.useState<Option[]>([]);
  const [currentDbStatus, setcurrentDbStatus] = React.useState<RemDbStatus[]>(
    [],
  );
  const initialState: State = { message: null, errors: {} };
  const [state, formAction] = useActionState(
    UpdateRemediationAction,
    initialState,
  );

  async function onSubmit(data: TFormUpdateSchema) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    Object.entries(data)
      .filter(([_, value]) => value !== undefined)
      .forEach(([key, value]) => formData.append(key, value as string | Blob));

    console.log(formData);
    // await UpdateRemediationAction(formData);
  }

  async function showStatus(data: RemDbStatus[]) {
    toast({
      title: 'Current Database Status:',
      description: (
        <pre className="mt-2 rounded-md bg-slate-950 p-4">
          <code className="text-sm text-white">
            {JSON.stringify(
              data.map((item) => ({
                ...item,
                intended_remediation_date: item.intended_remediation_date,
              })),
              null,
              2,
            )}
          </code>
        </pre>
      ),
    });
  }
  // form.handleSubmit(() => formRef.current?.submit())
  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form ref={formRef} action={formAction} className="space-y-6">
        <div className="rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-4 md:p-6">
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="itService"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                <FormLabel className="block text-sm font-medium">
                  IT Service
                </FormLabel>
                <Popover open={serviceopen} onOpenChange={setServiceOpen}>
                  <PopoverTrigger className="inline-flex self-start" asChild>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        role="combobox"
                        className={cn(
                          'justify-between text-wrap',
                          !field.value && 'text-muted-foreground',
                        )}
                      >
                        {field.value
                          ? options_service.find(
                              (option) => option.value === field.value,
                            )?.label
                          : 'Select IT Service'}
                        <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                      </Button>
                    </FormControl>
                  </PopoverTrigger>
                  <PopoverContent className="w-[400px] p-0">
                    <VirtualizedCommand
                      height="208px"
                      options={options_service}
                      placeholder="Search IT Service ..."
                      selectedOption={field.value}
                      onSelectOption={async (currentValue) => {
                        field.onChange(currentValue);
                        setServiceOpen(false);
                        const t_versions = await fetchTechVersion(currentValue);
                        setTechOptions(t_versions);
                        form.resetField('softwareProductVersionName');
                        form.resetField('intendedRemediationDate');
                      }}
                    />
                  </PopoverContent>
                </Popover>
                <FormDescription>
                  This is the IT service for which the remediation date should
                  be updated.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="softwareProductVersionName"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                <FormLabel className="mt-6 block text-sm font-medium">
                  Technology Version
                </FormLabel>
                <Popover open={techopen} onOpenChange={setTechOpen}>
                  <PopoverTrigger className="inline-flex self-start" asChild>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        role="combobox"
                        className={cn(
                          'justify-between text-wrap',
                          !field.value && 'text-muted-foreground',
                        )}
                        disabled={!watch('itService')}
                      >
                        {field.value
                          ? techoptions.find(
                              (option) =>
                                option.value.trim() === field.value.trim(),
                            )?.label
                          : 'Select Technology Version'}
                        <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                      </Button>
                    </FormControl>
                  </PopoverTrigger>
                  <PopoverContent className="w-[300px] p-0">
                    <Command>
                      <CommandInput
                        placeholder="Search Technology Version"
                        className="h-9"
                      />
                      <CommandList>
                        <CommandEmpty>
                          No Technology Version found.
                        </CommandEmpty>
                        <CommandGroup>
                          {techoptions.map((tech) => (
                            <CommandItem
                              value={tech.label}
                              key={tech.value}
                              onSelect={async (currentValue) => {
                                field.onChange(currentValue);
                                setTechOpen(false);
                                const {
                                  itService,
                                  softwareProductVersionName,
                                  ...rest
                                } = form.getValues();
                                const data = await fetchCurrentRemediationData({
                                  software_product_version_name:
                                    softwareProductVersionName,
                                  it_service: itService,
                                });
                                setcurrentDbStatus(data);
                                await showStatus(data);
                                form.resetField('intendedRemediationDate');
                              }}
                            >
                              {tech.label}
                              <CheckIcon
                                className={cn(
                                  'ml-auto h-4 w-4',
                                  tech.value.trim() === field.value?.trim()
                                    ? 'opacity-100'
                                    : 'opacity-0',
                                )}
                              />
                            </CommandItem>
                          ))}
                        </CommandGroup>
                      </CommandList>
                    </Command>
                  </PopoverContent>
                </Popover>
                <FormDescription>
                  This is the technology version for which the remediation date
                  should be updated.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="intendedRemediationDate"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                <FormLabel className="mt-6 block text-sm font-medium">
                  Remediation Date
                </FormLabel>
                <Popover open={remediate} onOpenChange={setRemedDateOpen}>
                  <PopoverTrigger
                    className="inline-flex gap-x-4 self-start"
                    asChild
                  >
                    <FormControl>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        className={cn(
                          'text-left font-normal',
                          !field.value && 'text-muted-foreground',
                        )}
                        disabled={
                          !watch('softwareProductVersionName') ||
                          currentDbStatus.every((obj) => obj.eim_scope)
                        }
                      >
                        {field.value ? (
                          format(field.value, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
                        ) : (
                          <span>Pick a Date</span>
                        )}
                        <CalendarIcon className="ml-auto h-4 w-4 opacity-50" />
                      </Button>
                    </FormControl>
                  </PopoverTrigger>
                  <PopoverContent className="w-auto p-0" align="start">
                    <Calendar
                      mode="single"
                      selected={field.value}
                      onSelect={field.onChange}
                      disabled={(date) => date < new Date('1960-01-01')}
                      captionLayout="dropdown-buttons"
                      fromYear={2000}
                      toYear={2050}
                      initialFocus
                    />
                  </PopoverContent>
                </Popover>
                <FormDescription>
                  Pick a Remediation Date for the chosen Tech Version and IT
                  Service.
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="remark"
            render={({ field }) => {
              return (
                <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                  <FormLabel className="mt-6">Remark</FormLabel>
                  <FormControl>
                    <Textarea
                      placeholder="Tell us a little bit about your remediation journey"
                      className="w-1/2 resize-none"
                      {...field}
                      disabled={watch([
                        'itService',
                        'softwareProductVersionName',
                      ]).every((i) => i === undefined)}
                    />
                  </FormControl>
                  <FormDescription>
                    Comments you may like to store about remediation
                    information.
                  </FormDescription>
                  <FormMessage />
                </FormItem>
              );
            }}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="remediationType"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem className="flex flex-col">
                <FormLabel className="mt-6 block text-sm font-medium">
                  Remediation Type
                </FormLabel>
                <Popover open={remedtype} onOpenChange={setRemedTypeOpen}>
                  <PopoverTrigger className="inline-flex self-start" asChild>
                    <FormControl>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        role="combobox"
                        className={cn(
                          'justify-between text-wrap',
                          !field.value && 'text-muted-foreground',
                        )}
                        disabled={watch([
                          'itService',
                          'softwareProductVersionName',
                        ]).every((i) => i === undefined)}
                      >
                        {field.value
                          ? remediation_types.find(
                              (option) =>
                                option.remediation_type === field.value,
                            )?.remediation_type
                          : 'Select Remediation Type'}
                        <CaretSortIcon className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
                      </Button>
                    </FormControl>
                  </PopoverTrigger>
                  <PopoverContent className="inline-flex self-start p-0">
                    <Command>
                      <CommandInput
                        placeholder="Search Remediation Type"
                        className="h-9"
                      />
                      <CommandList>
                        <CommandEmpty>No Remediation type found.</CommandEmpty>
                        <CommandGroup>
                          {remediation_types.map((remed) => (
                            <CommandItem
                              value={remed.remediation_type!}
                              key={remed.remediation_type}
                              onSelect={async (currentValue) => {
                                field.onChange(currentValue);
                                // form.setValue('remediationType', currentValue);
                                setRemedTypeOpen(false);
                              }}
                            >
                              {remed.remediation_type}
                              <CheckIcon
                                className={cn(
                                  'ml-auto h-4 w-4',
                                  remed.remediation_type!.trim() === field.value
                                    ? 'opacity-100'
                                    : 'opacity-0',
                                )}
                              />
                            </CommandItem>
                          ))}
                        </CommandGroup>
                      </CommandList>
                    </Command>
                  </PopoverContent>
                </Popover>
                <FormDescription>
                  Remediation Types of a Product
                </FormDescription>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <Button type="submit" className="mt-6">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
}

I then use a server action to take in formdata from react-hook-form and update my database as in this file:
'use server';
import { evergreen, remediation } from '@/drizzle/schema';
import { db } from '@/drizzle/db';
import { sql, eq, and } from 'drizzle-orm';
import { UpdateRemediation } from './definitions';
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';
import { State } from './definitions';

export async function UpdateRemediationAction(
  prevState: State,
  formdata: FormData,
) {
  const rawFormData = Object.fromEntries(formdata) as Record<string, string>;
  console.log(`this is raw form`, rawFormData);

  const parsedData = UpdateRemediation.safeParse(rawFormData);
  // console.log(parsedData.error);

  if (!parsedData.success) {
    return {
      errors: parsedData.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
      message: 'Invalid form data',
    };
  }

  const { itService, softwareProductVersionName, ...rest } = parsedData.data;

  const objtoUpdate = {
    ...rest,
    intendedRemediationDate:
      parsedData.data.intendedRemediationDate?.toISOString(),
  };
  const updateData = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries([objtoUpdate]).filter(([_, value]) => value !== undefined),
  );

  try {
    await db
      .update(evergreen)
      .set(updateData)
      .where(
        and(
          eq(evergreen.itService, itService),
          eq(evergreen.softwareProductVersionName, softwareProductVersionName),
        ),
      );
    revalidatePath('/dashboard/inventory');
  } catch (error) {
    // throw new Error(`Database Error: ${error}`);
    // console.log(error);
    // return {
    //   message: `Database Error: ${error}`,
    // };
  }
  redirect('/dashboard/inventory');
  // if (Object.keys(updateData).length === 0) {
  //   console.log({
  //     message: 'Form Data Cannot Be Empty',
  //   });
  //   return {
  //     message: 'Form Data Cannot Be Empty',
  //   };
  // } else {

  //   revalidatePath('/dashboard/inventory');
  //   redirect('/dashboard/inventory');
  // }
}

And here is my zod schema:
const FormSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  itService: z.string({
    required_error: 'Please select an IT Service.',
  }),
  softwareProductVersionName: z.string({
    required_error: 'Please select a technology version',
  }),
  intendedRemediationDate: z.date().optional(),
  remark: z.string().optional(),
  // .transform((val) => (val === '' ? undefined : val))
  // .refine(
  //   (val) =>
  //     val === undefined ||
  //     val === '' ||
  //     (val.length >= 10 && val.length <= 100),
  // {
  //   message:
  //     'Remark must be at least 10 characters and at most 100 characters, or left blank.',
  // },)

  remediationType: z.string().optional(),
  modifyAt: z.string(),
});

export const UpdateRemediation = FormSchema.omit({ id: true, modifyAt: true });

export type TFormSchema = z.infer<typeof FormSchema>;
export type TFormUpdateSchema = z.infer<typeof UpdateRemediation>;

export type State = {
  errors?: {
    intendedRemediationDate?: string[];
    remark?: string[];
    remediationType?: string[];
  };
  message?: string | null;
};

I have a problem that for some unknown reason, only the field remark seems to be passed to the server action, here is the outout of console.log
{remark:'llllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll'}
